# How to mock context.getBeansWithAnnotations with Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I have created an interface **Client** with its two concrete implementations
clientA and clientB and annotated them with my custom annotation.

```
public interface Client{
    public void dosomething();
}

@Component
@Myannotation
public class clientA implements Client {         
    public void doSomething(){
         sysout("Client A do something");
    }
}

@Component
@Myannotation
public class clientB implements Client {         
    public void doSomething(){
       sysout("Client B do something");
    }
}
```

Now I am calling the overriden methods of both clientA and clientB from Alien class.

```
@Component
class Alien{
   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext context;  

   public void performOperation(){
      Map<String, Object> beans = 
               context.getBeansWithAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
      for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: beans.entrySet()) {
          Client c = (Client)entry.getValue();
          c.doSomething();
      }

   }
}
```

I am facing problem with writing test method for performOperation.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class AlienTest
{
   @InjectMocks
   Alien a;

   @Test
   public void testperformOperation(){
       //how to Mock for beans
       assertEquals(expected, a.performOperation());
   }
}
```

1) How should I write testperformOperation method(allowed to change the return type of **performOperation** method from void to any other type)

2) Is there any better way to get list of all implementations for Client interface without creating custom annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you first refactoring Alien to make it more testable using Dependency Injection idea which its dependencies (i.e Client) can be injected from outside rather than hard coded inside a method which always get from the spring context:

```java
@Component
public class Alien{

  private List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();

  @Autowired
  public Alien(List<Client> clients) {
        this.clients = clients;
   }

  public void performOperation(){
     for(Client c: clients) {
          c.doSomething();
      }
  }
}
```

If you simply want to inject all Client implementation to the Alien , you just need to `@Autowired List<Client>` into Alien which Spring will already help you to inject all the Client implementation to it out of the box. No need to create `@Myannotation`

Once you make the Alien 's dependencies injectable (i.e a list of client) , you can simply inject a mock to it and verify `performOperation()` really invoke all of `Client` 's `doSomething()`:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class AlienTest{

  @Mock
  private Client mockClientA;

  @Mock
  private Client mockClientB;

   @Test
   public void testperformOperation(){
   List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
   clients.add(mockClientA);
   clients.add(mockClientB);

     Alien alien = new Alien(clients);
     alien.performOperation();  

     verify(mockClientA).doSomething();
   verify(mockClientB).doSomething();
   }
}
```

Comment: yes. too much typing mistake for me. just revised .thanks

Comment: What if I want to use `@InjectMocks Alien`, instead of `Alien alien = new Alien(clients)` , what changes required?

Answer (score 1):

I’ll answer both parts of your question, but I believe the first approach is inferior and the second is the go-to approach.

1. If you want to stick with your custom annotation approach, you need to have a `@Mock ApplicationContext applicationContext` in your test class. In the test method (or setup method) you need to mock the call to `applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation` and return an appropriate map containing your bean (possibly also a mock)
2. You can easily inject all beans to a class by injecting a List of the appropriate type. In your case

   - get rid of @Autowired ApplicationContext
   - add an @Autowired List (or, preferably, use constructor injection)

This will also make the tests simpler, no need to mock ApplicationContext.
For example, see https://dzone.com/articles/load-all-implementors